# Prove that if M = supS for some nonempty bounded set S, then there exists an increasing sequence sn, of points S such that lim sn = M

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Prove that if M = supS for some nonempty bounded set S, then there exists an increasing sequence sn, of points S such that lim sn = M

Is this a monotone sequence? Do I need to use Cantor's principle

Comment: By increasing you presumably mean non-decreasing.

Comment: For any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $s\in S$ with $s>M-\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $S$ is bounded then $M$ is a real number. Then for each positive natural number, let $S_n$ denote the set 
$$S_n:=\{s\in S: M-1/n<s\le M\}$$

Since $M$ is the $\sup S$, then $M-1/n$ cannot be an upper bound for $S$ and there is some $s\in S$ such that $M-1/n<s$ and so $S_n$ is non-empty for each $n\ge 1$. Using the axiom of choice (or the axiom of countable choice) we can then find a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $a_n\in S_n$. In particular $s_n\in S$ and $M-1/n< a_n\le M$ for all $n$. Then by the squeeze theorem $(a_n)\rightarrow M$

Answer (score 0):

Let $M=SupS$. Assume there is some $\epsilon>0$ so that $M- \epsilon > s_n$ for all $n$. Can $M$ still be  $SupS$ ?